# JSF : maven_eclipse_integration : src/main/java does NOT appear

Tags: maven, jsf-2, m2eclipse

I am stuck, with the same problem : src/main/java does NOT appear, for my first jsf project itself. I always get the Iclasspathentry kind=4 error. I am using eclipse kepler with m2eclipse=1.4 version, jdk 1.7, and pom has as well as set with 1.7 , and set with 2.1.7,........ I am stuck at first jsf itself.
Please help, my project delivery is within a week.

Answer (score 0):

Try closing eclipse. Remove all eclipse files (.classpath, .project and .settings).
Open eclipse and re-import your maven project. That usually cleans out cached problems.